# Amazon SNS publish topic to Baidu Cloud Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, baidu

Is there any way to publish a topic from Amazon SNS to multiple mobiles with Baidu cloud service?

Currently, when publish a message from SNS to baidu, I need specify EndpointArn which created with userid and channelid information. These information represent a mobile device. 
==> I only publish from SNS to a specific mobile device represented by userid and channelid.

But I need publish a topic from SNS to multiple mobile devices which registered the topic.

I tried: smart phone register a topic (example: hello) to Baidu then SNS publish the same topic (hello) to Baidu. But the smartphone COULD NOT receive the topic message from SNS.

Anybody know how to make it work?

Comment: am also having somewhat similar issue 
 ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49249030/baidu-push-notification-channelid-and-userid-is-not-unique .. any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I just faced this problem, but finally find out it is required to set the following three message attributes for it to work:

- AWS.SNS.MOBILE.BAIDU.DeployStatus
- AWS.SNS.MOBILE.BAIDU.MessageType
- AWS.SNS.MOBILE.BAIDU.MessageKey

Here is the reference:
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePushBaiduPublish.html