# Baidu Push Notification - ChannelId and UserId is not unique

Tags: android, ionic-framework, baidu, great-firewall-of-china, baidu-map

I am developing ionic mobile application and integrating with Baidu push service.

Plugin used : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-push-baidu

When I call startWork plugin method, am getting ChannelId and UserId.

Issue :

I login with User 1. I get token channelId C1 and UserId U1. Now, I logout.

I login with User 2. But still I get C1 and U1 which is same as what I got for User 1.

Now my question is :

If I send notification to User 1, will it trigger in device since ChannelId is same for User 1 and User 2.

For GCM and APNS, device registration gives different tokens but in case of Baidu ChannelId is same.

Please clarify.

Any update ?

Comment: @ice1000 any thoughts ?

Comment: No idea. I haven't been working on mobile developing for months. Sry